# SSM Session dies how to ping ec2 instance over SSM so session remains active?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, devops, boto, aws-ssm

SSM session only stays active for up to 60 minutes via AWS settings. I have to find some form of work around to keep my Python/Boto3 session up until its ended by me.

Can someone please suggest a way to ping instance SSM via Python/Boto?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you referring to the SSH session?

Comment: How are you using boto3 via SSM? Are you using [Port Forwarding](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/)?

Comment: @jellycsc I'm using port forwarding where first pipe is SSM connection to instance and the second connection is SSH.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, that is correct; Connection looks something like this: ssh -L port:host:5432 -o ProxyCommand="aws ssm start-session --target target --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'" user@address

Comment: So it stops 60 minutes after starting the SSM connection, even if traffic goes across the port forwarding? [Specify an idle session timeout value - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-preferences-timeout.html) says it will timeout after inactivity. So, the challenge is how to make it "see activity".

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, you're absolutely correct. I need to emulate activity from my Python script for SSM connection to not idle off after 60 minutes.